# Javamail, hide real sender's address to recipient?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I want to send mail with `javamail` but I don't want the recipient to reply me.

I want to display my real adress `myrealadress@abc.com` to `no-reply@abc.com`.

For the `reply to`, I use :

```
messageMail.setReplyTo(new Address[]{new InternetAddress("no-reply@abc.com")});
```

but I can see the real sender in mail box. So I use :

```
messageMail.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myrealadress@abc.com", "no-reply@abc.com"));
```

but I can see the `myrealadress@abc.com` adress in recipient mail box...

So, is there a way to completely hide the sender adress mail to recipient please ?

Comment: Since you use `myrealadress@abc.com` in from address

Comment: check my post, I use it but it is always possible to user to see real adress in mail

Comment: to summarize, when I test to send mail without using nowhere my real address in my code, the sender can see my real adress nevertheless...

Comment: @OlivierJ, Have you done with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it by assigning from name like

```
messageMail.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@abc.com", "WebMaster"));
```

But usually Informing the from name and from address is good practice for sending mail. Use from name with from address and reply to. Mention like `do not reply to the sender`

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. I see `Webmaster` but when I'm pointing mouse on it, I see my real address

Comment: If you're using a free public mail server (Gmail, Yahoo, etc.) it will usually force your message to contain your real address, to prevent you from sending spam with a fake address.

Comment: @BillShannon Yes. Gmail use to say `via`, there can see real from address in mail header.

Comment: hmm ok thank you. I will pray to not being spammed so ;) I use Google indeed.